# Better solution than else if with ranged data

Tags: java

I have a simple java method that returns colors based on the HSB value converted from an RGB. It works (needs some tweaking), but I use a series of else if and nested if statements to return the data I want. I had heard that HashMaps and String Factories were better, but I couldn't see how these worked with ranged data. Is there a better solution that works with ranged data like this?

Snippet:

```
public static String getColorName() {
    getHSB(rgb);
    if(hsbH >= 45 && hsbH < 75) {
        if(hsbS > 0 && hsbS < 45 && hsbB > 70){
            return "White/Off White";
        } else if(hsbS > 0 && hsbS < 45 && hsbB < 10) {
            return "Dark Yellow";
        } else {
            return "Yellow";
        }
    } else if(hsbH >= 15 && hsbH < 45) {
        if(hsbS > 0 && hsbS < 45 && hsbB > 70){
            return "White/Off White";
        } else if(hsbS > 0 && hsbS < 45 && hsbB < 10) {
            return "Dark Orange";
        } else {
            return "Orange";
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully, there is a lot of repetition and very obvious structure in your code! Here is what I came up with, as far as I remember most of the job was done using automatic refactorings in my favourite IDE:

```
public static String getColorName() {
    getHSB(rgb);
    if (hsbH < 15)
        return colorName(hsbB, hsbS, "Red");
    if (hsbH < 45)
        return colorName(hsbB, hsbS, "Orange");
    if (hsbH < 75)
        return colorName(hsbB, hsbS, "Yellow");
    //...
}

private static String colorName(int hsbB, int hsbS, String color) {
    final boolean smallSaturation = hsbS > 0 && hsbS < 45;
    if (smallSaturation) {
        if (hsbB > 70)
            return "White/Off White";
        if (hsbB < 10)
            return "Dark " + color;
    }
    return color;
}
```

If you use *Sean Patrick Floyd*'s advice of using `TreeMap` this code will be even simpler (I could help myself):

```
public static String getColorName(final int hsbH, final int hsbB, final int hsbS) {
    NavigableMap<Integer, String> colorRanges = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    colorRanges.put(0, "Red");
    colorRanges.put(15, "Orange");
    colorRanges.put(75, "Yellow");
    //...
    return colorName(hsbB, hsbS, colorRanges.floorEntry(hsbH).getValue());
}
```

Note that `colorRanges` ranges should be defined once and reused.

---

Risking being downvoted here is a nice way you can write this literally using Scala and simple DSL:

```
implicit def toIntBetween(x: Int) = new {
    def between(left: Int) = new {
        def and(right: Int) = {
            x >= left && x < right
        }
    }
}

def getColorName = {
    if(hsbH between 45 and 75) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Fancy `if(hsbH between 45 and 75)` construct actually translates to:

```
if(toIntBetween(hsbH).between(45).and(75))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a single range dimension, you can use a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with [`floorEntry()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) or [`ceilingEntry()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry%28K%29). But for multiple range dimensions I don't really see how to make this happen.

Instead, what I would do is specify some kind of rule Object:

```
public class Rule{

    private int maxH = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int maxS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int maxB = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int minH = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int minS = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int minB = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public Rule maxH(int maxH){this.maxH=maxH;return this;}
    public Rule minH(int minH){this.minH=minH;return this;}
    public Rule maxS(int maxS){this.maxS=maxS;return this;}
    public Rule minS(int minS){this.minS=minS;return this;}
    public Rule maxB(int maxB){this.maxB=maxB;return this;}
    public Rule minB(int minB){this.minB=minB;return this;}

    public boolean appliesTo(HSB hsb){
        return minH < hsb.getH() && hsb.getH() < maxH &&
               minB < hsb.getB() && hsb.getB() < maxB &&
               minS < hsb.getS() && hsb.getS() < maxS ;
    }

}
```

Construct them like this:

```
Rule rule = new Rule().maxB(123).minH(45).maxH(122);
```

And keep them in a map together with the Strings (you'll probably want to implements equals() / hashCode() first).

Now iterate over the map's entrySet(), and when a rule applies, you have your color name.

Comment: Instead of hacking in a map, why not add `name` to the `ColorRule`? Then, at the start of the application, the color rules are created and defined in some known color list, and to lookup a color you just do a findAll on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an HSB class could definitely make the code more readable. Below I'm using the `ceilingEntry()` method of `TreeMap` which could be argued is less readable than a multitude of if statements with explicit minimums and maximums.  However, it has the added benefit of not leaving any holes. (i.e., if somebody sets up ranges of 0-5, 6-10, etc., the `if` statements need to include a `<=` or `=>` as part of the comparison or there will be a gap.)

```
public class HueSatBright {
    int hue,sat, brightness;

    static TreeMap<Integer,String> colorMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();

    static {
        colorMap.put(15,"Red");
        colorMap.put(45,"Orange");
        colorMap.put(75,"Yellow");
    }

    HueSatBright(int hue, int sat, int brightness) {
        this.hue = hue;
        this.sat = sat;
        this.brightness = brightness;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (isKindaWhite()) ? "White/Off White" : getModifier() + getBaseColor();
    }

    public boolean isKindaWhite() {
        return (sat > 0 && sat < 45 && brightness > 70);
    }

    public String getModifier() {
        return (sat < 10) ? "Dark " : "";
    }

    public String getBaseColor() {
        return colorMap.ceilingEntry(hue).getValue();
    }

}
```